# Sequence of tenses (the present perfect and the past simple

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> 1 And now that a month has passed, she decided to write a review.
>
> 2 And now that a month has passed, she has decided to write a review.
>
> 3 And then that a month had passed, she decided to write a review.

I am pretty sure that 2 is correct. But I don't think it fits the idea of her having written a review already. If she has written it yet, her decision is no longer connected with the present. Which makes 1 correct. But I am not sure.

What about 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, (2) is correct (if the review hasn't been finished yet).

(1) doesn't make sense because the past simple doesn't go with **now**. If the report has already been written you would have to say **After a month [had passed], she decided to write a review.**

(3) isn't a valid sentence because we don't say **then that** (time had passed).

Comment: Is this possible "And now that a month had passed, she decided to write a review."?

Comment: That is possible if the narrator of a story is taking us back in time to the day she decided.